# Subclassing UITableViewCell --> grey background

Tags: ios, uitableview, subclass

I have a problem that I can't resolve.

When subclassing the UITableViewCell and fill the array data, I have something like :

[image]

This is my class TrackViewCell

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TrackViewCell : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var iconPlayLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTrackLabel: UILabel!

}
```

and how I use it :

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TrackViewCell") as TrackViewCell
let track = self.tracks[indexPath.row]
cell.nameTrackLabel.text = track.title
cell.iconPlayLabel.text = "▶️"
return cell
}
```

and some others revenants screens :
[image][image]

I can also send you the xcode project ( it's not personal, it's a tutorial )

Thanks you in advance all.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem today, turned out that changing the cells height solved it. 
I guess somehow the content of the cell did not fit into it so it corrupted, at least that's my guess....
So try changing the height of the cell in storyboard / interface builder and see if it works.